# Selenium WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the below exception when i am trying to run my first test case using selenium webdriver in java. Can someone help me out plssss.....

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 48523
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Mar 29, 2018 7:34:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any     stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'NIL-MKODAGA-D13', ip: '172.16.20.242', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '9.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome=    {chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f), userDataDir=C:\Users\mkodagan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4652_10811},    takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=65.0.3325.181, platform=WIN8_1,   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,    takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 1a39885769cc96406e2f2732c361c049
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:96)
    at com.ham.scripts.ClickOnAllLinks.main(ClickOnAllLinks.java:44)
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) 
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'NIL-MKODAGA-D13', ip: '172.16.20.242', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '9.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

The error clearly says that the *Selenium Client* and *ChromeDriver* is not getting detected back as in :

```
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'  
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.37*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.4.0** of which is a bit older.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.4.0* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @DebanjanB, the problem lies with chromedriver version. From the logs you can see that it uses chromedriver=2.33.506120 which is bit old. Check for the latest version from "https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads".

I was also facing the same problem the problem could be solved by updating the chrome driver. 
You could uses below approaches for solving it.

1. Running `npm install -g chromedriver`
2. Manually updating the chromedriver, I found the chromedriver being used by the appium resides in below location. 
   *C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.5.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win.*

Replace this chromedriver with the latest one and run your code. It should work fine.

Note: The location could be OS specific, so search for chromedriver exact location.